# brightcove videojs CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED after full screen and coming back

Tags: android, cordova, brightcove

I am working with brightcove player using reactjs and cordova . I am getting videojs CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED only in samsung devices only after I play video in full screen and coming back. what can be issue can anyone suggest ??

[image]